# Во время вёрстки лого и текст находятся на разных уровнях, хотя топ одинаковый

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, figma

Как должно быть

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как у меня

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.header-container-logo__image {
  position: absolute;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  left: 115px;
  top: 33px;
}

.header-container-name__text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 197px;
  height: 24px;
  left: 129px;
  top: 33px;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #160647;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="header-container">
    <a class="header-container-logo__image" href="#">
      <img class="header-logo__image" src="files\Rectangle 131.png" alt="logo">
    </a>
    <p class="header-container-name__text">MONEYEXCHANGE</p>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте такой вариант верстки, он правильнее.

```css
.header-container-logo__image {
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #160647;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header-container-logo__image>img {
  width: 35px;
  margin-right: 6px;
  transition: transform .2s;
}

.header-container-logo__image:hover>img {
  transform: rotate( 24deg);
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="header-container">
    <a class="header-container-logo__image" href="#">
      <img class="header-logo__image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f6/Choice_toxicity_icon.png" alt="MONEYEXCHANGE"> MONEYEXCHANGE
    </a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

А зачем абсолютами выравниваешь? Обёртке (`.header-container`) присвой `display: flex, justify-content: space-between`. И для выравнивания по высоте дай свойство `align-items: center`.

И абсолюты используй по-минимуму, где это действительно нужно, а то адаптация будет приносить одну сплошную боль.